# Sorting JSON response with Python

Tags: python, json, sorting

Need to help to figure out how to sort JSON reponse by highest to lowest number, for example. here is part of JSON reponse below:

```
{
"queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"name": "Riven's Cutthroats",
"entries": [
  {
     "leaguePoints": 812,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "losses": 277,
     "playerOrTeamName": "CLG Bunso",
     "playerOrTeamId": "19732914",
     "wins": 356
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 567,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "losses": 56,
     "playerOrTeamName": "SKT Frost",
     "playerOrTeamId": "66401633",
     "wins": 160
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 751,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": true,
     "losses": 421,
     "playerOrTeamName": "C9 Hard",
     "playerOrTeamId": "47836799",
     "wins": 494
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 587,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": true,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "losses": 157,
     "playerOrTeamName": "ShadowFiendv",
     "playerOrTeamId": "71181475",
     "wins": 265
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 1109,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": true,
     "losses": 353,
     "playerOrTeamName": "ApoIlo Price",
     "playerOrTeamId": "7250",
     "wins": 425
  },
```

Now, I already grabbed the necessary info i needed, as below:

```
def getChallengerLadder(region, APIKey):
    URL = "https://" + region + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region +     "/v2.5/league/challenger?type=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=" + APIKey
    print (URL)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()


   responseJSON3 = getChallengerLadder(region, APIKey)
    x = 0
    while True:
        print (responseJSON3['entries'][x]['leaguePoints'], responseJSON3['entries'][x]['playerOrTeamName'] )
         x += 1
```

As a result i get a list as follows (again, below is only a small sample):

```
608 Z Y Xydra
552 Silas Kroeger
1109 ApoIlo Price
601 Blem
587 Boy vs Girl
701 l am Bjerg
560 duo to homecomin
```

I want to sort this list from largest to smallest number, but i cant figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreaciated! IS there a better way to do it then i already done? I assume you would have to put the response in the array and sort the array? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by `leaguePoints`

(I use `json` module only to create full working example)

```
text = '''{
"queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"name": "Riven's Cutthroats",
"entries": [
  {
     "leaguePoints": 812,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "losses": 277,
     "playerOrTeamName": "CLG Bunso",
     "playerOrTeamId": "19732914",
     "wins": 356
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 567,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "losses": 56,
     "playerOrTeamName": "SKT Frost",
     "playerOrTeamId": "66401633",
     "wins": 160
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 751,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": true,
     "losses": 421,
     "playerOrTeamName": "C9 Hard",
     "playerOrTeamId": "47836799",
     "wins": 494
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 587,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": true,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "losses": 157,
     "playerOrTeamName": "ShadowFiendv",
     "playerOrTeamId": "71181475",
     "wins": 265
  },
  {
     "leaguePoints": 1109,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "I",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": true,
     "losses": 353,
     "playerOrTeamName": "ApoIlo Price",
     "playerOrTeamId": "7250",
     "wins": 425
  }
]
}'''

import json

# simulate `getChallengerLadder`
responseJSON3 = json.loads(text)

result = sorted(responseJSON3['entries'], key=lambda x:x['leaguePoints'])

print result
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. In your example, you set "text" as a variable to the JSON response. How would i do that if i dont have the text on hand? Basically the text is only available when i prompt the JSON from API, and it can change every few minutes. For example, I cannot do something like this :
       `text = '''`
           `print (responseJSON3)`
      `''''`

because then responseJSON3 is treated as a string inside quotes? SOrry if this seems simple, Im just learning Python

Comment: I use `json.loads(text)` only to simulate API and get result similar to `responseJSON3` to create working example. I changed variable `j` into `responseJSON3` in answer.

Comment: `print` send text on the screen and you can't assign it to variable. You can `text = str(some_object)` but to get correct JSON text it is better to use `text = json.dumps(responseJSON3)`.  (but you don't have to convert `resonseJSON3` to text in my example)

Comment: Thanks, i actually got it figured out last week, forgot to take a look at your reponse again, i used your sorted() method, assigned it to variable, then printed then 2 entries that i needed (leaguePoints and playerOrTeamName)